# When the heapsort worst case occurs?

Tags: time-complexity, heap-sort

The best-, average-, and worst case time complexity of Heapsort for $n$ *distinct keys* are all $\Theta(n \lg n)$.

> What are the worst-case inputs for heapsort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the [paper@arXiv2015: A Complete Worst-Case Analysis of Heapsort](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01459v1.pdf) by M. A. Suchenek.

This paper gives a rather involved lower bound; see Abstract and Theorem 12.2 on page 94.

To the specific question,

> Example of a 500-node worst-case array for Heapsort, created by my
>   Java program, is included in Appendix A.3 page 110.